# Make IntelliJ resolve dependencies from modules in same project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Using IntelliJ 2016.2.5, I seem to be unable to make it resolve Gradle dependencies which are in the same project.

Project structure is as follows:

```
firstModule
-> build.gradle // 1
-> settings.gradle // 2
secondModule
-> build.gradle // 3
-> settings.gradle // 4
```

Contents of first `build.gradle` (1):

```
group 'de.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {mavenCentral()}
dependencies {}
```

And `settings.gradle` (2):

```
rootProject.name = 'test'
```

The contents of the second `build.gradle` (4) are:

```
group 'de.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {mavenCentral()}

dependencies {
    compile ('de.test:test:1.0-SNAPSHOT')
}
```

And second `settings.gradle` (4):

```
rootProject.name = 'testdep'
```

Both modules are imported as Gradle projects and are set to `auto-import enabled`.

I know from maven projects, that IntelliJ - as well as Eclipse - does resolve those dependencies to the respective modules in the project/workspace. But with Gradle it seems to not recognize the dependencies. After every change in the module `test` I need to run the explicit gradle tasks `clean` and `build` before the module `testdep` seems to pick up the changes. And this process is not even reliable, if I don't change the version. This is most likely because of the gradle caching, but it is annoying, nevertheless.

Using the command line argument `--refresh-dependencies` is not a real solution because it makes the build times of our project (the one above is only for demo purposes) unbearable. Also, I would love to *not* having to use the gradle calls explicitly.

Any ideas/improvements how to handle such a situation?
Does it work with Eclipse, any experiences?
Will this be fixed in IntelliJ 2016.3 (I saw some improvements in the gradle area for that release).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do will be possible using the new [Composite Builds](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-composite-builds) functionality in Gradle. [Support for IntelliJ IDEA](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/10/intellij-idea-2016-3-eap-gradle-composite-builds-and-android-studio-2-2/) is coming soon.

Comment: Although this DOES solve most of the issues, one problem remains: If I change the version of the dependency to `firstModule` in `secondModule`, e.g. to test an older version, it looks like IntelliJ does NOT skip the local module and instead download the correct one from the repository. So, overall, this solution is still far from what I am used to when using Maven ...